# Is there way to use Java 8 features with Android library project?

Tags: android, java-8

I followed the [Android Java 8 Features manual](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html). It works well for Android application project. But when I try to use it with Android library project I get

```
Error:Library projects cannot enable Jack. Jack is enabled in default config.
```

**Partial solution:**
I enabled lamdba expression with [Gradle Retrolambda Plugin](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda).

Comment: AFAIK, nope as of today with AS 2.1.2

Comment: It's telling you that it's already enabled in the default configuration. You should be able to use it .

Comment: @DanielHolst No, by default configuration, it means that it is enabled by @sasha_tm in his gradle script in the `defaultConfig` section and does not indicate that it is enabled by default.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue and tried different approaches. It now works for me without using retrolambda (which produced some weird error during runtime). Also Jack is not active for the same reason you already mentioned.
There is an interesting bug post at google.com about this topic: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211386

Here is my build.gradle script, I used the workaround from the bug post to fix the "MethodType not found" exception during compilation.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Java8 not fully supported in library projects yet, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211386
// this is a temporary workaround to get at least lambdas compiling
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xbootclasspath/a:" + System.properties.get("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. I also faced the problem that I can't debug library project when Jack is enabled for main application project.

Comment: It doesn't work with the latest build tools, which is 25.

ERROR: LibClass.java:18-19: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.lang.Runnable

Comment: Also now getting the "Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.lang.Runnable" error when compiling with Jack. Fell back to use Retrolambda after spending a few hours of searching for a new solution. :(

Comment: Also make sure that JAVA_HOME has been set in the Environment Variables.

Comment: Starting from 14. of march the jack/jill toolchain is deprecated:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html

I would recommend using retrolambda until java 8 support is available with the previous toolchain is available. I will be supported starting from Android Studio 3.0.

Here is more information about future support and migration notes: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Answer (score 0):

This sure has been a long ride. I tried all possible combinations of the gradle plugin, the *experimental* gradle plugin + `retrolambda` + `Jack` etc, but with no luck. Until now. From Android Studio 3.0 Preview 1 or later (and, consequently, the Android Gradle plugin `3.0.0-alpha1` or later), the `Jack` toolchain is deprecated and replaced by some new bytecode transformation - *sugaring*, used in conjunction with the standard `javac` compiler.

With this setup I've personally (finally!!!) been successful in using Java 8 features such as lambdas in a library project.

This page has all the techy info as well as migration help etc: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: Did moving your library to Java 8 also force consuming apps to be compiled with Java 8 support?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I'd expect that using lambdas and such features in the library does not force Java 8 compatibility on the client app, because these features are accomplished through sugaring. Using Java 8 *APIs* such as streams is of course a different story, as it might affect the minSdkVersion of the library, and in turn, the app.

Comment: Hi @PseudoPsyche, sorry for the long delay. Yes, it did. Without Java 8 compatibility I actually got a strange dex error, and it took a while to realize what it was.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! That's somewhat unfortunate. So, this was the case even when not explicitly using Java 8 APIs?

Comment: Yeah, actually I think so, but I can double check. BTW, seeing as you refered to this as unfortunate, what would a reason for not having Java 8 compatibility in an app, except for perhaps a really low minSdkVersion (which might exclude using the library anyway)?

Comment: Well, I suppose it's _potentially_ unfortunate. I meant that in regard to a library only, since it adds another requirement on consuming apps. Not a big deal in the long run, but there's usually some pushback from consumers when requiring a change they may not have planned on yet. :/

Comment: Just moving to Java 8 did not force apps to be compiled with Java 8, but using lambda in the library actually caused Dex error... I also think this is unfortunate since lots of my library's consumers will still use java 7 to compile their apps..