# How to use jackOptions for android library project

Tags: android, java-8, android-studio-2.1

I have an application code in android studio, which I want to convert it to library project so that I can use it as library in other application.
The build.gradle of the library project is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    //applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

 }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

/* support libraries*/
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'

/* google play services libraries*/
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'

}
```

I am using android studio 2.2.1 and jdk 1.8,
jdk 1.8 requires jackOptions

it says:
Error:Library projects cannot enable Jack. Jack is enabled in default config.
if i disable jackOptions then my library is not working as due to jdk 1.8 it says jackOptions are necessary and getting following errors.

```
app:generateDebugSources 
app:mockableAndroidJar
app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies 
app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
myapplication:generateDebugSources
myapplication:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
myapplication:mockableAndroidJar
myapplication:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated entry in the settings. Just remove the following lines from your build.gradle:

```
jackOptions {
        enabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Olivier M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916101/oliver-m), you have a working workaround here : [Is there way to use Java 8 features with Android library project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360596/244911).

The import part is :

```
// Java8 not fully supported in library projects yet, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211386
// this is a temporary workaround to get at least lambdas compiling
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xbootclasspath/a:" + System.properties.get("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar"
    }
}
```

Comment: inside module or project. ?